# Experience Manager Performance

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager

In looking into Experience Manager, and reviewing the log files for the session preview web service, I see what looks like excessive transactions.

I am the sole user of the system. When I perform an edit in XPM and look at the log files they seem to indicate that the transactions was started 193 times (all the same transaction id).

```
2016-10-12 07:54:56,749 INFO  StorageManagerFactory - Starting storage transaction: a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3
2016-10-12 07:54:56,749 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,749 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,749 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,749 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,749 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,749 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,749 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,749 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,749 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,749 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,749 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,749 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,765 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,781 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,781 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,781 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,781 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,781 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,781 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,781 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,781 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,781 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,781 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,781 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,781 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,781 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,781 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,781 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,781 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,781 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,796 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,812 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
2016-10-12 07:54:56,827 DEBUG FSEntityManager - Starting transaction a9430c5a-b606-4cb7-9972-9bf373a44ab3.
```

Is this normal, or how can it be resolved?

Comment: can you change DEBUG to ERROR?

Comment: I could, but does not really answer my question. I am interested why it is happening so freqently (every few milliseconds)